# How can I restore blog posts and contents from an old WordPress Folder

Tags: wordpress, blogs, vs-web-site-project

I decided to rebuild my WordPress website, I was able to save the folder contents of the old website, but I need to be able to get the blog posts and contents of the old website to the new website. Where and how can I find the old blog posts to copy into the new website?

Comment: The posts are stored in the database, you won't find them in any directory.
There are a lot of tutorials in the internet that explain how to migrate wordpress, did you make the effort to search?

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to get concrete directions on getting out just sections of the database and merging to the new one. All I need is just the posts, so I don't want to get everything from the old database

Comment: WordPress has a built-in export function, which allows you to export posts only. The exported file can be imported in the new WP. All of this you can find in the WP docs.

Comment: So I also tried setting up the new website with the old database, but I don't know how I can access the contents in the new website

Comment: I wasn't able to export the previous posts before the website was taken down, I just have the database and the folders from the file manager, but I don't how to integrate everything back together...I can simply upload the old website because it had major errors.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it myself after exploring so many options, I finally restored the right tables from my old database